# My Discord bot reponds multiple time to one command and I want to know if there's a way to send it only once

Tags: javascript, node.js, command, bots, discord.js

When I make a command, my discord bot will respond multiple time instead of once. I'm using JavaScript and can't find any ways to make it work.

Here's my part of my main script:

```js
const Discord = require('discord.js');
const client = new Discord.Client();
const fs = require("fs");
 
const prefix = '-';
 
client.commands = new Discord.Collection();
 
const commandFiles = fs.readdirSync('./commands/').filter(file => file.endsWith('.js'));

for(const file of commandFiles){
    const command = require(`./commands/${file}`);
    client.commands.set(command.name, command);
}
 
client.categories = fs.readdirSync("./commands/");

client.once('ready', () => {
    console.log('Bot is online!');
});
 
client.on('message', message => {
    if(!message.content.startsWith(prefix) || message.author.bot) return;
 
    const args = message.content.slice(prefix.length).split(/ +/);
    const command = args.shift().toLowerCase();
 
    if(command === 'ping'){
        client.commands.get('ping').execute(message, args);
    }
}
```

Here's my subfolder for the command ping:

```js
module.exports = {
    name: 'ping',
    description: "this is a ping command!",
    execute(message, args){
        message.channel.send('pong!')
    }
}
```

Thanks for helping

Answer (score 1):

Currently writing one too and I dont see anything wrong with this, is it possible your node is running twice?

Comment: How do I check if it's running twice? (sorry I'm a beginner)

Comment: Restart your computer just in case there are multiple instances.